# Sqlalchemy: How do I set key length of a multi-column primary key?

Tags: sqlalchemy, composite-primary-key

I know that I can use `mysql_length = xxx` to set the length of an Index.

But how to apply this constraint to a multi-column primary key?
(using `PrimaryKeyConstraint`)

P.S: My primay columns are A, B (A is an `Integer`, B is a `String(256)`, the question is how to cut it down when added to the composite key)

Comment: I doubt such index will make sense. Primary key implies unique, but I can't imagine where unique constraint should applied to part of key.

Comment: @DenisOtkidach What do you mean about 'applied to part of key'? Is there any way to inform the framework that I regard this Index as a primary key?

Comment: For example if you have unique (including primary) key with length 2 on string field, then values `"abc"` and `"abd"` will be considered duplicates.

Comment: @DenisOtkidach Indeed. Do you mean that I should try to use a pure index instead of primary key in this situation because of some potential unexpected features?

Comment: I don't know what task you are trying to solve with this index, so I can't suggest you anything.

Comment: @DenisOtkidach My task is simple and does not require truncated key.